# How to bind a variable prop to a v-for slot

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to have a list component, which renders a list of router-links with a scoped slot for each of the router-link. The to-prop of the router-link should be configurable by the parent.

The parent component should be able to configure the to-prop of the router link, without having to implement the router-link itself. Or if it has to implement the router-link itself, the list component should be able to pass classes to every router-link.

I've created a codepen showing the problem that I want to solve. Of course if you have any questions about it or if anything's unclear let me know.
https://codepen.io/Buffalom/pen/KKPmJPx

This is a summary of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
<router-link v-for="item in items" to="/" class="abc">
    <!-- :to should be configurable by the parent -->
    <slot :item="item"></slot>
</router-link>
```

I expect the parent to be able to render a list with a given array of items but configure each router-links to-prop itself.

### Update

The ideal way I'd like to take would be something like this in the parent component:

```
<List :items="items" :to="`/1/${item.name}`">
    ...
```

As the item in the to-prop each item in items would be used on the v-for router-link in the list component itself. Kind of like a reverse scoped-slot...^^

Comment: From where does the `to` attributes dynamic data would come from, is it in `items` array?

Comment: @ambianBeing I imagine it would be a path string put together on the parent component consisting of a substring and data from each individual item of the items array. E.g. "/1/${the name of the current item}"

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? You just need to make `to` a dynamic prop.

```
<router-link v-for="item in items" :to="item.url" class="abc">
    <!-- :to should be configurable by the parent -->
    <slot :item="item"></slot>
</router-link>
```

#### Update

If you don't have the url, look into [vue-router named routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html). Taken from the doc and adapted lightly:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/1/:itemName',
      name: 'item',
      component: MyItemPage
    }
  ]
})

<router-link
    v-for="item in items"
    :to="{ name: 'item', params: { itemName: item.name }}"
    class="abc"
>
    <slot :item="item"></slot>
</router-link>
```

Comment: That's true, I could add a url prop to the items. I would prefer to do it some other way such as maybe passing a template string to the list component that's then used as the url but I guess that'll do for now. Thanks!

Comment: @Tom Well without your router configuration it's hard to give a complete answer. You can also look into https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html if you don't have the urls directly. Also, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark.

Comment: I added an update explaining what I'd like to be able to do. I'm actually using nuxt, just didn't think it's worth noting cause it doesn't really have anything to do with nuxt.

Comment: thanks for the update. As you can see in the codepen I'd like to use that list component from different parents which should be able to configure an entirely different route. So in component1 I'd like to implement the list component with items1 and each item should link to '/1/${item.name}' and in component2 I want to use items2 and each item should link to '/2/${item.name}'. Not only the item name is different but the entire route should be.

Comment: @Tom in that case you can define multiple routes with different names and use a configurable route name instead of the static string `'item'` I used.

Comment: ah yes right, and then I can pass the route name as a normal property to the list component. That's true. Helps in the case described, but if I see it right it wouldn't help if those different routes required different parameters right?

Comment: @Tom you can pass as much or as little information as required to build the route inside your link component. This can include the route name, route parameters, query params, etc.

Comment: yes, but again it cannot be a property that's item specific only generic info that's available to the parent component